# angularjs - using {{}} binding inside ng-src but ng-src doesn't load

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to bind a value to the ng-src of an img HTML element to no avail.

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller='footerCtrl'>
<a href="#"><img ng-src="{{avatar_url}}"/></a>
</div>
```

AngularJS code:

```
app.controller('footerCtrl',function($scope, userServices)
{
$scope.avatar_url='';
$scope.$on('updateAvatar', function()
{$scope.avatar_url = userServices.getAvatar_url();}
);
}

app.factory('userServices', function($rootScope){ 
var avatar_url='';
return{  setAvatar_url: function(newAvatar_url)
{ avatar_url = newAvatar_url; $rootScope.$broadcast('updateAvatar');}}
);
```

I would like to update the avatar_url variable in the `ng-src` every-time its respective variable(avatar_url) in the user Service is updated. The variable in the user Service is updated through a http.POST request to the server. I have checked that the response from the server does update the variable in the user Service which is then broadcast to the avatar_url variable in the `footerCtrl`.

However, the image element HTML does not reflect the changes at all. In fact, I have also tried to preset the avatar_url variable to a relative path to one of the pictures in my page, the image still shows nothing(the ng-`src` value is empty).  T

Comment: In the `userServices` you have a `setAvatar_url` function vs. in the controller you use the `getAvatar_url` function. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in replying, maybe the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jiaming/DvNA9/1 would be clearer in explaining the code. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is full of bugs...

Comment: I was looking ng-src attribute for usage, and question already gave me the answer thanks! :)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Changing the `ng-src` value is actually very simple. Like this:

```html
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img ng-src="{{img_url}}">
<button ng-click="img_url = 'https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3261/2801924702_ffbdeda927_d.jpg'">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsFiddle of a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hx7B9/2/

Comment: Thanks. this was what I was really trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/jiaming/DvNA9/12/ . But the main problem was that I was rendering it as a jinja template in the app engine server which caused conflicts with all the {{}} braces.

Comment: Oh, that you mean. You can change the `{{}}` if you like: http://jsfiddle.net/THjQe/1/

Comment: wow, thanks for that reply, I didn't know you can do that. (:

Comment: You might want to be sure that you are not breaking any plugins before you change Angular's `{{}}`. There are some that relies on `{{}}`.

Answer (score 8):

We can use `ng-src` but when `ng-src's value` became `null`, `''` or `undefined`, `ng-src` will not work.
So just use `ng-if` for this case:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hx7B9/299/

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl"> 
        <a href='#'><img ng-src="{{link}}" ng-if="!!link"/></a>
        <button ng-click="changeLink()">Change Image</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is a bug.  Had me confused.  ng-src was displaying a previous image.