# Ng-source not work for image

Tags: html, angularjs

I try to load image with dynamic values and html with angular but is not work.I try this:

```
<img ng-src="img/{{product.Category}}/{{product.id}}.jpg">
```

and this also:

```
<img src="img/{{product.Category}}/{{product.id}}.jpg">
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out the console for errors

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394578/angularjs-using-binding-inside-ng-src-but-ng-src-doesnt-load

Comment: @Antonis Kountouretis your ng-src implementation is correct. Inspect the image element and you will find the dynamic values. I think there is no such image to load

Comment: make sure image is path is sure

Comment: Check this link http://plnkr.co/edit/oohW6AZxnuuQQQwdWtPM?p=preview dynamic values are getting loaded

Comment: make sure the image is available in that path and check whether all images are jpg or not

Answer (score 2):

```js
function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.link = 'https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3261/2801924702_ffbdeda927_d.jpg';
    $scope.changeLink = function() {
        $scope.link = 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8455/8048926748_1bc624e5c9_d.jpg';
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl"> 
        <a href='#'><img ng-src="{{link}}" ng-if="link"/></a>
        <button ng-click="changeLink()">Change Image</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

We can use `ng-src` but when `ng-src's` value became null, '' or undefined, ng-src will not work. So just use `ng-if` for this case - make sure the image is available in that path

Answer (score 0):

try to put this output in "alert()" in your controllers to check the value.
if the output is not empty, check your controllers.
check your db if images are stored with their extension or not !